# Position of controls changes on hiding some controls in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, controls, jframe, show-hide

I have a JFrame and in that I have many controls. I call this frame a number of times, and sometimes I have to hide some of controls. When I hide the controls, the position of other controls which are not hidden change automatically. I want to avoid this behaviour. Please help in this regard.

```
  pnlRec.setVisible(true);
  btnNew.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Add a simple snippet of your code to convey this - it shouldn't need to be more than 30 lines of code and it should compile all on its own.   It's something that can help yourself narrow down the problem scope, and help us by providing a formal [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: This is the default behavior of many layout managers.  You're going to need to provide more details about your layout to help us

Comment: as @MadProgrammer referred, you may achieve your desired behavior by use a separate layout for each control instead of adding controls into 1 layout.

Comment: I feel it is less confusing to the user to simply *disable* the control if not applicable amongst a larger group of controls.  For example, if encoding MP3 & 'Variable Bit Rate' is selected, then disable the combo. that specifies a range of 'Bits Per Second' (128 KBPS, 192 KBPS..).

Comment: @MadProgrammer i am using groupLayoutManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a solution based on `CardLayout`. Place all the components to be hidden in a `JPanel` with `CardLayout`. Each the panel should have 2 cards - the original component and empty panel. Instead of hiding the component just swap the cards showing the empty card panel.

That should keep the layout the same.